Exceptional Lenz-Barlotti classes IVa.3 and IVb.3
On this web-site, devoted to the Lenz-Barlotti classification of projective planes, it is written that the class IVa.3 (and its dual IVb.3) is somewhat exceptional, because it contains exactly one projective plane up to an isomorphism, namely the (dual) near-field plane of order 9.
In his classical textbook Dembowski writes that this results is due to Andre (1955) and refers to his paper ``Projektive Ebenen über Fastkörpern'' (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01180628), which is unfortunately inavailable for me.

Question. Is there any readable self-contained proof of this result of Andre (that the Lenz-Barlotti class IVa.3 contains just one plane)?

As I understand the proof somehow reduces to analyzing the structure of near-fields (coordinatizing projective planes of Lenz-Barlotti type IVa.3).

For me, at least, this paper is freely available by following the link below:
https://eudml.org/doc/169486
I didn't read the paper carefully, but hopefully this answers the question.
